Random carrier PWM for the dc-dc converter
I have been implementing a control software for the buck dc-dc converter. The converter with following parameters \$R_L=19.0\cdot 10^{-3}\,\Omega\$, \$L=10^{-3}\,\mathrm{H}\$ has a battery at its output. The BJT is only in the schematic, in reality the IGBT is being used.

The main goal of the control software is to realize a current control loop (controling the current of the inductor). For the EMI and acoustic noise reasons I have attempted to use the random carrier pulse width modulation (the frequency band for the carrier is \$2000-4000\,\mathrm{Hz}\$). Due to simplicity of the implementation of the control algorithms I have been using fixed sampling frequency \$10\,\mathrm{kHz}\$.
In other words the pulse width modulation is independent to the sampling process.
Below are the outcomes of my experiments with the current control

carrier frequency


current control loop (\$i^{*}=100\,\mathrm{A}\$)


duty cycle


frequency spectrum of the current



What is surprising for me is the actual value of the current. I have been thinking about the causes of its noisy waveform. I have only one idea namely that the actual value of the current is distorted due to the aliasing effect. If it's really the reason I have no idea how to avoid this phenomenon in a situation when the sampling process is independent to the PWM carrier generation. Can anybody help me with this problem?

How about a schematic?

This converter is very poorly designed for the amount of current you have it outputting.

@Hearth thank you for your reaction. May I ask you for explanation?

At this kind of current level, you definitely want to use synchronous rectification, and a BJT for the main switch is also probably not a great choice. A low switching frequency like you're using is sensible, though, assuming you can afford to use large enough reactive components.

A multi-phase interleave system is probably desirable as well; this reduces stress on the inverter (peak voltage and current) as well as reducing ripple at the input and output capacitors.
